# Why is the following regex removing the bounding characters inside single quotes?

Tags: javascript, regex

This code turns straight single quotes into curly single quotes:

```
var result = 'This \'is an\' example'.replace(/(?<!\w)\'\S(.*?)\S\'(?!\w)/g, '&lsquo;$1&rsquo;')
alert(result)
```

I thought the output would be:

> This ‘is an’ example

But the output was this:

> This ‘s a’ example

I'm not sure why the bounding characters inside the quotes are being removed.

Why is this and how to fix it?

https://jsfiddle.net/gz5wjoqx/

Answer (score 4):

You are *matching* the two `\S` parts without capturing them:

```
.replace(/(?<!\w)\'\S(.*?)\S\'(?!\w)/g
//                 ^^     ^^
```

So when you replace with the first capture group surrounded by quotes:

```
'&lsquo;$1&rsquo;'
//      ^^
```

The characters in the `\S` are not in the `(.*?)` capture group, so they're not included in the `$1` replacement.

Put everything you want to replace with into the capture group:

```js
var result = 'This \'is an\' example'
  .replace(
    /(?<!\w)'(\S.*?\S)'(?!\w)/g,
    '&lsquo;$1&rsquo;'
  );
console.log(result)
```

(also note that `'` doesn't need to be escaped in a pattern)

You can also consider using `\B` ("not a word boundary") instead of negative lookaround for `\w`, which will make the pattern compatible with older browsers *and* more concise:

```js
var result = 'This \'is an\' example'
  .replace(
    /\B'(\S.*?\S)'\B/g,
    '&lsquo;$1&rsquo;'
  );
console.log(result)
```

Comment: So easy to fix ... Thanks a lot for the answer and suggestion.